# What are Karate Kid's abilities and are they similar to Deadpool's?

Tags: marvel, dc, martial-arts

Does anyone know any more details about Karate kid from DC? I posted [this pic](https://static.comicvine.com/uploads/scale_medium/1/10812/1653295-ilc009.jpg) of him fighting Marvel's Deadpool and noticed there are similarities in that both heroes have *some hidden abilities*.

I was just wondering what can Karate kid exactly do?

Comment: He can put wax on, then take wax off? :p

Comment: I felt my answer to this one was about as comprehensive as you're likely to get. Is there anything else you'd like to see before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 6):

Karate Kid appears to be human-normal with superior fighting abilities. The [DC wikia](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Val_Armorr_(Pre-Zero_Hour)) describes him thusly;

- Karate Kid is a master of every known martial art in the 31st century
- He is classified as a Class 15 fighter (Batman is only Class 12)
- Val Armorr is an expert in hand-to-hand combat
- Val's martial arts ability includes proficiency with assorted melee weapons such as swords and knives, though Val almost never uses such items for combat.

In [various continuities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karate_Kid_(comics)) he possesses a [Legion 'flight ring'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legion_Flight_Ring) allowing him to fly and travel into space.

He is typically depicted with no superpowers (a key plot point in the cartoon episode Legion of [Superheroes: The Karate Kid](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1126268/)), but he does have superior mind-control as a result of his martial arts training and can shut off pain.

In one of the cartoons ([JLA Adventures: Trapped in Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JLA_Adventures:_Trapped_in_Time)) he appears to possess some sort of extra-sensory perception of a person's 'weak points' which he can then attack.

---

As to the question of his similarity to Deadpool, there really isn't any. They're both canny fighters but Deadpool has a *host* of different super-abilities, not least his famously high levels of regeneration

Comment: Everyone in the Legion of the Superheroes gets a flight ring.

Comment: @Buzz - Sure, or else he'd just be a dude stuck on the ground